# Logout button php

Tags: php, logout

I have this code and need the code to add a logout button, can anyone write out the code for a log out button that will log out the user, I read something about destroy session but do not know how to write the code out, thank you!

```
<?php
    include 'connection.php';
    //start of checking if user is logged in code
    if (!valid_credentials) {
    header('Location: login.php');
    exit();
    }

$_SESSION['user'] = 'username';


if (!isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    header('Location: login.php');
    exit();
}
    //end of logged in code and starting a session

$query = "SELECT * FROM people";
$result = mysql_query($query);
While($person = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<h3>" . $person['Name'] . "</h3>";
    echo "<p>" . $person['Description'] . "</p>";
    echo "<a href=\"modify.php?id=" . $person['ID']. "\">Modify User</a>";
    echo "<span> </span>";
    echo "<a href=\"delete.php?id=" . $person['ID']. "\">Delete User</a>";
}
?>
<h1>Create a User</h1>
<form action="create.php" method="post">
    Name<input type ="text" name="inputName" value="" /><br />
    Description<input type ="text" name="inputDesc" value="" />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 31):

Instead of a button, put a link and navigate it to another page

```
<a href="logout.php">Logout</a>
```

Then in `logout.php` page, use

```
session_start();
session_destroy();
header('Location: login.php');
exit;
```

Comment: `session_unset` is from the deprecated session API before `$_SESSION` existed. Use `unset`, or don't call it at all as you're destroying the session anyway.

Comment: This is insane. Logout button should be POST, not GET.

Comment: @Nakilon Classic case of complicating things when not necessary. Do you see any data being passed via the anchor link? There is absolutely no need to go for POST when everything is already being done on the server side.

Comment: @asprin, it is just HTTP stardard -- if you change smth on server (invalidating session) it should be POST. Imagine if I in my SO profile edit the image src="" to point not to projecteuler site but to "/logout". You'll be logged out when you look in my profile. It is fundamental that logout button should be POST.

Comment: @Nakilon By that logic, I can modify the post variables pretty easily too. If someone is skilled enough to know how to alter GET, he will surely know how to do the same for POST too.

Answer (score 7):

When you want to destroy a session completely, you need to do more then just

```
session_destroy();
```

First, you should unset any session variables. Then you should destroy the session followed by closing the write of the session. This can be done by the following:

```
<?php
session_start();
unset($_SESSION);
session_destroy();
session_write_close();
header('Location: /');
die;
?>
```

The reason you want have a separate script for a logout is so that you do not accidently execute it on the page. So make a link to your logout script, then the header will redirect to the root of your site.

Edit:

You need to remove the () from your exit code near the top of your script. it should just be

```
exit;
```

Comment: Why is there an extra die even after the redirect?

Comment: @ina good question. The reason the die is on there is because if you ever want to continue after the header redirect, it die prevents code from being executed after you redirect. In this case it is not really needed but it is good practice if you plan to do more after the redirect.

Comment: use $_SESSION=[];,  unset($_SESSION) will make you can not recreate session.

Comment: @wolfrevo Better to use [$_SESSION = array();](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php#example-3902)

Comment: do I need to `die` or `exit()` at the end?

Comment: @webNoob13 If you are redirecting using the `header` function it is best practice to exit your script so that code that comes after your redirect doesn't get executed. It's there just to be safe. :)