# How to logout a user in php?

Tags: php, session, logout

I am making a login system and I just got it to work, and now I am having difficulty making a logout feature for my website. Its not actually hosted yet, so security will come later. I have tried various uses of session_destroy and unset, but i cannot get it to work. Any help would be appreciated.

My PHP

```
<?php
session_start();
/*This is the equivalent of login.php*/
$database = "forum";  // the name of the database.
$server = "localhost";  // server to connect to.
$db_user = "root";  // mysql username to access the database with.
$db_pass = "";  // mysql password to access the database with.
$table = "members";    // the table that this script will set up and use.
$link = mysql_connect($server, $db_user, $db_pass);
mysql_select_db($database,$link);

if (isset($_POST['fsubmitted'])) {
// Get the data passed from the form
$username = $_POST['username'];
$pass = $_POST['pass'];

// Do some basic sanitizing
$username = stripslashes($username);
$pass = stripslashes($pass);
$encryptedpass = md5($pass);

$sql = "SELECT * from members where username = '$username' and password = '$encryptedpass'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);


$count = 0;

$count = mysql_num_rows($result);

if ($count == 1) {
     $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = "true";
    header("Location: index.php"); // This is wherever you want to redirect the user to
    exit();

} else {
     $_SESSION['loggedIn'] = "false";
     echo '<div class="errormsgbox">Your username and password combo was incorrect!</div>';
     var_dump($result);
    echo $sql;
}
}

if ($_SESSION['loggedIn'] = "true") {
    echo '<div class="success">You are now logged in!</div>';
}

if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && (time() - $_SESSION['loggedin'] > 1800)) {
    // last request was more than 30 minutes ago
    session_unset();     // unset $_SESSION variable for the run-time 
    session_destroy();   // destroy session data in storage
}
$_SESSION['loggedin'] = time(); // update last activity time stamp

?>
```

Comment: Note that MYSQL_* functions are depreciated. You should use MYSQLI or PDO.

Comment: Security should be there all along not come after.

Comment: Where are you starting the session?

Comment: First missing and most important element: `session_start();`. I will let you have a look at the answers below.

Comment: Where should the session_start(); go?

Comment: @Zippylicious it (most of the time) must be located as your first line, after your opening `<?php` tag.

Comment: OK, I added the session start at the beginning of my code.

Comment: @Zippylicious I take it you're addressing me now. Please add the `@` symbol followed by my name to address me personally. Now, you can keep going with the answers that have been provided to you below.

Comment: @Zippylicious See this answer on SO for a `logout` method http://stackoverflow.com/a/12209491/1415724 (After Googling "logout button session php") wink

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
session_start();
```

With either of the following:

```
session_destroy();
session_unset();
unset($_SESSION["loggedin"]);
$_SESSION = array();
```

Answer (score 2):

I can see two errors in your code:

- You have not started the session
- You have not told the code which session to unset/destroy

#### Starting the session:

Put this as the first line of your PHP code: `session_start();`

#### Logging out

Lets take a closer look at this block of code:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && (time() - $_SESSION['loggedin'] > 1800)) {
    // last request was more than 30 minutes ago
    session_unset();     // unset $_SESSION variable for the run-time 
    session_destroy();   // destroy session data in storage
}
```

You have not told the code which session to `unset` or `destroy`!

To do that, you must include a session variable inside of the parentheses.

Try this code:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && (time() - $_SESSION['loggedin'] > 1800)) {
// last request was more than 30 minutes ago
session_unset($_SESSION['loggedin']);     // unset $_SESSION variable for the run-time 
session_destroy($_SESSION['loggedin']);   // destroy session data in storage
}
```

All i did was, told the code which session to `unset` and `destroy`

**UPDATE**
Try this instead if that didn't quite work for you.

```
if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && (time() - $_SESSION['loggedin'] > 1800)) {
// last request was more than 30 minutes ago
unset($_SESSION['loggedin']);     // unset $_SESSION variable for the run-time 
$_SESSION['loggedin'] = "false";
}
```

Another good thing to take a look at is having a logout button. This is explained here: [Logout button php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12209438/logout-button-php/12209491#12209491)

I hope this helped you out, and let me know if I can be of further help!

Comment: I like the way you explained your answer, however there is one key element missing, the way (how) to use the logout method. I'll give you a clue: **"a link to"** (wink) http://stackoverflow.com/a/12209491/1415724

Comment: @Fred and PattyD I looked at the link that you provided to that other stack overflow logout question, and implemented it, but my system still seems to think i should be logged in. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @Zippylicious *"but my system still seems to think i should be logged in"*. What is it do you mean by that exactly? I don't understand.

Comment: @Fred The $_Session['loggedin'] variable is still repeating back as true, and that is what is determining whether or not the website puts up logged in content. It should be false.

Answer (score 0):

In your script to log someone out, simply have:

```
session_start();
unset($_SESSION);
session_destroy();
```

You should also call `session_start()` at some point in your login.php you have shown above.

Comment: Not "should", but **"must"** ;-) You should also state the position of `session_start();` to be, and in which files (wink)

Comment: @bizzehdee I put that code into a logout.php file and ran it after adding the session start, but my website still seems to think that $_SESSION['loggedin'] = 'true';, and not that it is false.

Answer (score 0):

I would try using this function:

```
function logout(){
    if(session_id() == '') { // start session if none found
        session_start();
    }

    session_unset();         
    session_destroy();
    unset($_SESSION['loggedIn']);
}
```

All you need to do to use this function is call logout(); where ever you want to have the person logged out.

Comment: I think the OP may not have the experience that you have in PHP and sessions. I suggest that you explain how to use this method.